# Enable automatic completing `\begin{env} \end{env}`

Tags: environments, texstudio

I'm using TeXstudio. Everytime I have to type `\begin{...}` and `\end{...}`. It would save me sometime if everytime I type `\begin{...}` the software automatically fill with `\end{...}`. How can I do this?

In addition, given that I have `\begin{env1} \end{env1}`, if I rewrite a environment, say `\begin{env2}`, is there a way to the program to automatically rewrite `\begin{env2}`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! The [user manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION113) mentions "If a enviroment is to be inserted, typing in the beginning of the environment name and pressing Ctrl+Alt+Space gives suggestions for adequate enviroments which are inserted completely with \begin{env}..\end{env}". I don't have TeXstudio so I can't test it, but maybe that would work.

Comment: I like this. I'll use ctrl+alt+space.

Comment: @Marijn Would you like to add an answer?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik as requested.

Comment: @Marijn Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [TeXstudio manual, Section 2.13](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION113) (emphasis mine):

> #### 2.13 Auto Completion
>
> Whenever you press `\` followed by a letter, a list of possible LaTex
>   tags is shown where you select the right one. If you write additional
>   letters the list is filtered, so that only the tags starting with the
>   already written text are shown. If the list contains words which all
>   start with the same letter combination, you can press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to complete
>   all common letters. If only one element is present in the list, <kbd>Tab</kbd>
>   selects this one to do the completion, like <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This behaviour is
>   similar to tab completion in bash shells. You can also press
>   <kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd> to open this list whenever you want. If a tag has different
>   options, a short descriptive text is inserted into your text, telling
>   you the meaning of each option. You can press <kbd>Ctrl+Left</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+Right</kbd> to
>   select all positions. Furthermore normal text can be completed by
>   starting to type a word and pressing <kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd>. All apropriate words
>   in the current document are used as possible suggestions.
>
> **If a
>   enviroment is to be inserted, typing in the beginning of the
>   environment name and pressing <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+Space</kbd> gives suggestions for
>   adequate enviroments which are inserted completely with
>   `\begin{env}..\end{env}`**
>
> And finally user tags can be assigned a
>   abbreviation which can also be used with completion. Just type in the
>   start of the abbreviation and start the completion with <kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd>.
>   The abbreviation should show up in the completion list, especially
>   marked with “abbreviation (template)”. If you change a command by
>   completing a new command, only the command name is substituted. The
>   same is true for environments, where the environment is changed in the
>   `\begin`- and `\end`-command.